Математические символы на СИ
Кто - нибудь может подсказать, как можно работать с математическими символами на СИ? Например, корректно их выводить, сравнивать и т.д. На python я знаю, что есть LateX. Есть ли что - то похожее для СИ?

LaTeX как формат документа существует безотносительно того, пишете вы на C или на Питоне.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715162/symbolic-computation-library-in-pure-c
